# how to parse a name out of a list for Kendo().ComboBox()

Tags: vb.net, razor, combobox, telerik

I'm using VB.Net, MVC, Razor, bootstrap and Telerik Kendo Combobox.  My requirement is to have all inputs, drop downs, and combo boxes on a page be the same width.  We have decided to use `style = "width: 100%"` inside of some `col-md-4`'s to accomplish this task.  Everything works fine until I introduce multiple dynamically generated combo boxes on the same page.

Prior to the re-sizing everything worked just fine using the following code:

```
@Code
Html.Kendo().ComboBox() _
.Name(Model.ListOfCategoryAttributeIDs(i)) _
.BindTo(values) _
.DataTextField("Text") _
.DataValueField("Value") _
.Filter("Contains") _
.Suggest(True) _
.MinLength(1) _
.Render()
End code
```

I've added the following line to my boxes which works fine on pages with one box (static name):

```
.HtmlAttributes(New With {Key .style = "width: 100%;"}) _
```

What I've come to realize is that my `Model.ListOfCategoryAttributeIDs(i))` does not parse out properly, the generated html skips the name tag altogether.  This allows the box to work properly, but causes the `width` key to be skipped in the rendering process.

These boxes are rendered inside of a Razor loop.  I've tried putting my desired name into a variable and passing that into the comboBox:

```
Dim nameOfBox = Model.ListOfCategoryAttributeIDs(i)
Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
.Name(nameOfBox)
......
```

Have also tried `.Name(nameOfBox.ToString)`

Have also tried giving the box a static name "box" which allows the first combo box to render with the proper width, but the remaining boxes are then rendered as normal text boxes (they all have the same name).

Is there someway that I can give each of my combo boxes a name that comes from a list of names that will allow them to render properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had similar problems to this one in other programming endeavors, and the best way that I've solved it is by creating your comboboxes inside a loop and appending `i` to the end of the name of each of your comboboxes. This way, there are no name collisions. So it would be something like: `.Name(Model.ListOfCategoryAttributeIDs(i) + i)`. (Not entirely sure about the syntax in this case.)